# Installing ubuntulooks and using themes for applications

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

I use ubuntu 14.04 with gnome3 shell.

Hi, I would like to start my application with gtk2 theme. I was using this tutorial:
http://urukrama.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/setting-a-custom-gtk-theme-for-specific-applications/
However i've encountered a problem, namely:
When i run app like this:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=/home/marcin/.themes/SlicknesS-black/gtk-2.0/gtkrc codeblocks
```

I get an error like this while running:

```
(codeblocks:19048): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "ubuntulooks"
```

I've tried installing this:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-ubuntulooks
```

but i get something like this in response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gtk2-engines-ubuntulooks is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  human-theme
E: Package gtk2-engines-ubuntulooks has no installation candidate
```

Or maybe there is any simplier way to make my code::blocks IDE dark-themed? :)

Comment: Indeed, the problem is realted to where you are installing the theme. There is a bug that affects the theme install in local folders. See the answer by @BitCommander that should solve the issue. You will need, of course, root permissions to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for my bad English.
I assume that you have the *SlicknesS-black* theme folder in `/usr/share/themes`.
Now execute this command in the terminal:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/SlicknesS-black/gtk-2.0/gtkrc codeblocks
```

I have another black theme. It works and looks like this:  [image: Code::Blocks screenshot with dark theme]

Tell me if it worked :)